# Chrome extension: how can I intercept a cookie?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, request

I need to grab the event when the page loads, when the cookies are sent and change them.

onBeforeRequest ---> my code ---> set cookie ---> set request

I found this event - chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.

In all the articles and the documentation says that I need to ask for cookies in the details.requestHeaders:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function (details) {
   console.log(details.requestHeaders)
},
{ urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
["blocking"]);
```

But it is always undefined.

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can only read the request headers using the events [`onBeforeSendHeaders`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeSendHeaders)and [`onHeadersReceived`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onHeadersReceived)

Also, you need to add `"requestHeaders"` to the optional argument. Example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
          //
          // details.requestHeaders // check me out
          return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
        },
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```